# How do I let my module implement user defined dataclass (Currently Use String)

Tags: haskell

I am still not entirely familiar with Haskell but when I was doing some exercises on my own, I came across a problem that would seem might come up in the future. Even if it doesn't I would like to know how to do this in the future.

Lets say I have a module

```
module UserType where

data ThisModulesData = UserData String | ThisModulesInternal Int

moduleMethod :: (ThisModulesData -> Int) -> ThisModulesData -> Int
moduleMethod func dat = case dat of
    UserData _             -> func dat
    ThisModulesInternal i -> i

processList :: (ThisModulesData -> Int) -> [ThisModulesData] -> Int
processList func xs = sum $ map (moduleMethod func) xs
```

Then if I wanted to use this module I would have something like

```
dataList :: [ThisModulesData]
dataList = [UserData "Type1", UserData "Type2", ThisModulesInternal 8]

processFunction :: ThisModulesData -> Int
processFunction (UserData command) = case command of
    "Type1" -> 1
    "Type2" -> 2
    _       -> 0
processFunction _ = 0

result :: Int
result = processList processFunction dataList
```

What I would like to do is replace the string with something more haskell like so it is type safe and could raise a compile error if I had

```
dataList = [UserData "Wrong", UserData "ThisIsWrong", ThisModulesInternal 97]
```

Thanks. I have had a pretty good time learning Haskell thanks to the help at StackOverflow.

EDIT:

To Clarify, I would like my module file to remain static and have things that need to change (if I want to add "type3" for example) happen in the user implementation of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a type parameter.

```
module UserType where

data ThisModulesData a = UserData a | ThisModulesInternal Int

moduleMethod :: (a -> Int) -> ThisModulesData a -> Int
moduleMethod func dat = case dat of
    UserData x            -> func x
    ThisModulesInternal i -> i

processList :: (a -> Int) -> [ThisModulesData a] -> Int
processList func xs = sum $ map (moduleMethod func) xs
```

And then

```
data Ours = Type1 | Type2
type OurData = ThisModulesData Ours

dataList :: [OurData]
dataList = [UserData Type1, UserData Type2, ThisModulesInternal 8]

processFunction :: Ours -> Int
processFunction command = case command of
    Type1 -> 1
    Type2 -> 2

result :: Int
result = processList processFunction dataList
```

n.b. I have also altered the definition of `moduleMethod` so that e.g. `processFunction` does not have to bother itself with `ThisModulesInternal`.

Comment: How could you enforce that your type parameter `a` is a `String` or `ByteString` or `Text`, etc.?

Comment: You can demand that the type parameter must implement a certain typeclass by mentioning it in the functions' types. e.g. `moduleMethod :: Monoid a => (a -> Int) -> ThisModulesData a -> Int` and `processList :: Monoid a => (a -> Int) -> [ThisModulesData a] -> Int`.